# Getting error while running Mobile automation script in appium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

[image]

Getting error while running automation script in appium.

[image]

[image]

I am running a Mobile automation script on a Windows Desktop system with below software set up.

Software Set-Up:

1.Android Studio

2.Appium

3.Mobile/Tablet connected to the system

4.Selenium/Appium Driver code for Automation

**Error**

```
apksigner stderr: ERROR: Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
Cannot use apksigner tool for signing. Defaulting to sign.jar. Original error: Command 'apksigner.bat sign --key 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\keys\\testkey.pk8' --cert 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\keys\\testkey.x509.pem' 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'' exited with code 1; StdErr: ERROR: Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.
[warn] [35m[ADB][39m Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
Unable to remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\Sumit.Chouhtel\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s RFXTBIC00014974 forward --remove tcp\:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb.exe: error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1''
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1568214375516 (20:36:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
```

Comment: What is not clear in `apksigner stderr: ERROR: Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.`?

Comment: Thank for replying rohit, But How I can resolve this error.

Comment: When you update your post, please try to keep the formating someone did for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable registry editing using these steps (assuming you have Windows 10)

1. Win + R (To open run commander window)
2. run `gpedit.msc`
3. Go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Prevent Access to Registry Editing Tools
4. Double click and set it to "disable"

[image]

Addition ways to achieve this https://www.techperiod.com/registry-edit-disabled-by-virus-fix/

Comment: Thank you for the response!!

I have got the below solution:

Need to click option as 'Only For Me' while installing the Appium Desktop app. (If we select 'For all users' option than there will be error in appium run).

Regards
Swati Dave

Answer (score 0):

I have got the below solution:

Need to click option as 'Only For Me' while installing the Appium Desktop app. (If we select 'For all users' option than there will be error in appium run).